# How to get a JavaDStream of an Object in Spark Kafka Connector?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka

I am using the Spark Kafka connector to fetch data from Kafka cluster. From it, I am getting the data as a `JavaDStream<String>`. How do I get the data as a `JavaDStream<EventLog>`, where `EventLog` is a Java bean?

```
public static JavaDStream<EventLog> fetchAndValidateData(String zkQuorum, String group, Map<String, Integer> topicMap) {
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaKafkaWordCount");
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));
    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
            KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap);
    JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
            return tuple2._2();
        }
    });
    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
    return lines;
}
```

My goal is to save this data into Cassandra where a table with the same specifications as `EventLog`. The Spark Cassandra connector accepts `JavaRDD<EventLog>` in the insert statement like this: `javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder("ks", "event", mapToRow(EventLog.class)).saveToCassandra();`. I want to get these `JavaRDD<EventLog>` from Kafka.

Comment: Do you mean you still wish to have messages as pair of strings and convert them? Or do you wish to use JavaReceiverInputDStream<EventLog>? Where exactly do you wish to bring in the EventLog type? Hvae you tried defining a receiver that accepts EventLog type and building  JavaDStream from that?

Comment: @Sunny My aim is to write the data into Cassandra. The Spark Cassandra connector accepts `JavaRDD<EventLog>` in the insert statement like this: `javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder("ks", "event", mapToRow(EventLog.class)).saveToCassandra();`. I want to get these `JavaRDD<EventLog>` from Kafka.

Comment: Do you also have access to the code that writes those EventLogs to kafka? Are there custom serializers implemented and are EventLogs serialized and written to Kafka as EventLogs?

Comment: @Sunny There are custom serializers which are sending to Kafka.

Comment: I believe it would be easiest to implement a custom receiver that would extend Receiver<EventLog> from org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver. In onStart() method you should just start consuming those events from Kafka and add a listener. If you have a active receiver and have a JavaStreamingContext you can just do jssc.receiverStream(receiver) to get the JavaReceiverInputDStream<EventLog>

Comment: @Sunny Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the overloaded [createStream](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html) method where you can pass the key/value type and decoder classes.

Example:

```
createStream(jssc, String.class, EventLog.class, StringDecoder.class, EventLogDecoder.class,
        kafkaParams, topicsMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2());
```

Above should give you `JavaPairDStream<String, EventLog>`

```
JavaDStream<EventLog> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, EventLog>, EventLog>() {
  @Override
  public EventLog call(Tuple2<String, EventLog> tuple2) {
    return tuple2._2();
  }
});
```

The EventLogDecoder should implement kafka.serializer.Decoder. Below example for json decoder.

```
public class EventLogDecoder implements Decoder<EventLog> {

 public EventLogDecoder(VerifiableProperties verifiableProperties) {
 }

 @Override
 public EventLog fromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   try {
     return objectMapper.readValue(bytes, EventLog.class);
   } catch (IOException e) {
     //do something
   }
   return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me the whole package for `StringDecoder`? What functions should the `EventLogDecoder` contain?

Comment: The third argument in `Function` should be `EventLog` like `Function<Tuple2<String, EventLog>, EventLog>()`.

Comment: Yes updated third argument. And the package for StringDecoder is kafka.serializer.StringDecoder. I have updated answer to include example Decoder.

Comment: I am getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` for `kafka.serializer.StringDecoder` while running `spark-submit`. I have added this dependency in the POM and I am not getting any error in Eclipse.

Comment: Are you providing the kafka jar or shading ?

Comment: My command is `C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\bin\spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.5.2 --class "com.jtv.spark.atnt.App" --master local[4] target\spark.atnt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and I have `<dependency> <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId> <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId> <version>0.8.0</version> </dependency>` in my POM.

Comment: try passing Kafka using --jars option

Comment: Changing the version of `spark-streaming-kafka` worked. I was previously using 1.6.2, changing it to 1.5.2 fixed the issue.